# Canon 350D upgrade

Tags: canon, lens-recommendation, upgrade, safari

I'm looking to improve on my partner's DLSR, the Canon 350D. We are going on safari and she wants to be able to take good long range shots. Should I just get her a good lens for the 350D or buy the upgrade to 1200D and get a long range lens?

My instinct is to go with the upgrade but any and all advice is more than welcome.

Cheers

Comment: This is unanswerable unless you tell us what lenses you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

"Upgrade" is in the eye of the beholder.  And learning to shoot fast-moving wildlife is not a skill you pick up overnight.  Even with the gear.  I would also point out that the Canon dSLR bodies tier by the number of digits in their model designation. A XXXXD is actually a *downgrade* from an XXXD, if you're looking at cameras in the same processor/sensor generation. In some ways, the 1200D is a downgrade from the 350D (e.g., it doesn't have an IR sensor for the Canon wireless shutter remotes).

I would also say that I was perfectly capable of shooting bird-in-flight shots with a 350D--after I bought an EF 400mm f/5.6L USM *and had been trying to get bird-in-flight shots for about two years.*  But probably an XXD or 7D body would be a better choice for serious wildlife shooting, because of the more sophisticated AF system and higher burst rate.

My recommendation would be to consider renting one of these bodies and a supertelephoto lens (say, a 100-400L, or one of the Sigma 400mm or 500mm lenses), and getting a monopod or tripod. And getting it early and practicing like hell before the trip.  Unless your partner plans on shooting wildlife as a regular thing, this sounds more like a special-occasion lens that's only going to be used the once, and a rental is going to cost a lot less than purchasing the lens and camera body together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, you've certainly given me a better idea. The lens/camera isn't just for this trip but a long term thing.